# Skip specic day while update in datetime SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have calculated a difference between two dates. I just want that in update how I skip Friday.Mean if set date is Friday then it move to Saturday.

```
UPDATE tblYearMaintenance            
SET DECMAINDATE = DATEADD(day, @DateDiference, MainDate)
WHERE MchId = @MchID AND SID = @SID AND ID > @ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `CASE` expression to check if the set date is Friday, in which case we can add one more day to that set date.

```
UPDATE tblYearMaintenance            
SET DECMAINDATE = CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, @DateDiference, MainDate)) = 'Friday'
                       THEN DATEADD(day, @DateDiference+1, MainDate)    -- Saturday
                       ELSE DATEADD(day, @DateDiference, MainDate) END  -- otherwise
WHERE MchId = @MchID AND SID = @SID AND ID > @ID                        -- original day
```